# PHP Error Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, database, parameters, numbers, token

I get this error  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/200228935/public_html/PHPWebServer/saveVideoGame.php on line 51

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO videogame(developer, name, cost, genre)      
        VALUES(:developer,:name,;cost,:genre)';
        //Allows special characters and slims the chance SQL injection
        $cmd=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $cmd->bindParam(':developer',$developer,PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
        $cmd->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
        $cmd->bindParam(':cost',$cost,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $cmd->bindParam(':genre',$genre,PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
        $cmd->execute();
```

Line 51 is $cmd->execute();

Comment: That looks like a typo. One of the placeholder prefixes in the SQL string is not like the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `;cost` to `:cost`

In the `$sql` string